# I have data with start and end values as character indexes for styles. How to convert that to valid html tags when start and end values overlap?

Tags: html, nested, formatting, tags

I have some data from another app that I need to convert to valid HTML.

The data would have a string like this:

"Hello, how are you?"

And then it would have a seperate set of data for the styling. So for example 'bold:start:2,bold:end:4'
'italic:start:5,italic:end:10'

Which would result in this output:

"He**llo**, *how are yo*u?"

The problem is the start and end values can overlap each other and sometimes span multiple paragraphs etc.

This is not data meant for the web but I need to convert it to work on the web.

I need to take data like the above and output it as valid text and html tags which are correctly nested.

I can't find any way to do this it seems really complex.

Does anyone know a library that can do this or have a method that is proven to work for this?

I tried so many different approaches and I keep ending up with fail cases.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Check out javascript [split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function or php [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function

Comment: I know those. Problem is the tags can overlap and don't follow any meaningful existing HTML structure. Split and explode just break a string into a one dimensional array. So this doesn't help, sorry.